# Setting MQTT subscriber sleep intervals via periodic broadcasting

Tags: sleep, cellular, mqtt

I have a system that consists of several field units which periodically (every 10 minutes) wake up and publish data to a MQTT topic. I am hosting the MQTT broker myself on a Linux server.

I would like to implement a feature that allows me to set the sleep period on these units via MQTT. Note, the units operate asynchronously from each other.

It seems like it would be straightforward to have the Linux server publish a sleep period to a specified topic when data is received from a field unit, but the field units take a significant amount of time to connect/subscribe to MQTT topics as they are using cellular data in remote areas. Since the delay to connect/subscribe is not consistent and could take 10s of seconds, it seems that a synchronous approach will not work well here.

I am considering having the Linux server broadcast a sleep period to a topic once every second or so as an alternative and having the field units subscribe to this topic once every wake cycle. Are there any major downsides to this solution?